# Random amount of random letters from array only giving one Element back

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I'm quite new to javascript so this question might be dumb.
So basicly what I'm trying to do is to have an array with the letters a-z for example. A random number from 1-10 is generated and saved in a variable which determins how many letters the function will return. After that the variable is given to another function which will pick random elements from the array and return them back to html. It's hard to explain I'm sorry

Everything works fine but it gives only one skin back at a time instead of the amount based on variable "letternum"

Heres where I'm at so far

```
var letters = [
    "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",
    "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
    "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
];

function letters() {
  var letternum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var i;

  for (i = 1; i < letternum; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length) + 1;
    var randletter = letters[random];
    document.getElelemtById('div').innerHTML = "Random letters picked:" + randletter;
  }
}
```

I do apologize for the title I couldn't find a better one

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code:

- You're misspelling `getElementById`.
- You're naming both the array and the function `letters`.
- You're overwriting previously written letters using `=`.
- You should use `Math.random() * (letters.length - 1)` to avoid getting `undefined` (due to index getting out of range).

```js
var letters = [
  "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i",
  "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
  "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
];

function lettersFunction() {  // a different name
  var letternum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var i;
  for (i = 1; i < letternum; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (letters.length - 1)) + 1;
    var randletter = letters[random];
    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += "Random letter picked: " + randletter + '<br>';  // += instead of =, and add a new line after each letter
  }
}
lettersFunction(); // calling the function
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: You seems to be enjoying it :)

Comment: @bhansa What I can say, I love solving problems that have maths in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElelemtById('div').innerHTML = "Random letters picked:" + randletter;
```

This line at the end of the loop changes the innerHTML, so you are left with just the last one in the random number. You could changes this to:

```
document.getElelemtById('div').innerHTML += "Random letters picked:" + randletter;
```

so they are appended.

Answer (score 0):

Your display function is inside your for loop-- meaning that it's going to display once for every letter it picks. What you want to do is to concatenate the letters together in the for loop and display them once:

```
 var letters = [
     "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i",
     "j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r",
     "s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
 ];

 function letters(){

     var letternum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
     var i;
     var randletter;
         for (i = 1; i < letternum; i++) {
             var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length) + 1;
             randletter += letters[random];
    }
     document.getElelemtById('div').innerHTML = "Random letters picked:" + randletter;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just update the innerHTML don't overwrite it. Remove the typos as well and use some other id for your div, other than div.

```
document.getElementById('numdiv').innerHTML += "Random letters picked:" + randletter;
```

Code:

```html
<div id="numdiv" onclick="randletters();">Click</div>

<script>
  var letters = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i",
    "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
    "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",
  ];

  function randletters() {

    var letternum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i < letternum; i++) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length) + 1;
      var randletter = letters[random];
      document.getElementById('numdiv').innerHTML += "Random letters picked:" + randletter + "<br>";
     }
      document.getElementById('numdiv').innerHTML += "<br><hr>";
    
  }
</script>
```